# TextBox with Date picker ? Date validation@ jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

well coming straight to point .

I am having a form with many controls and i am performing some sort of validations on it . I been stuck at one thing i have attached DATE-PICKER to one of My text-boxes and i want to validate Textbox accordingly .

I don't want to provide user to enter ANYTHING in textbox Rather i love to give him Calendar to select from when he clicks inside textbox .

**In Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="effectivedate" />
```

**Jquery :**

```
$('#effectivedate').datepicker();
```

Well any better solution or advice is appreciated .

PS: The thing why i am restricting is just because i don't user to enter some junk values .

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the taxtbox readonly:

```
 <input type="text" id="effectivedate" readonly="readonly" />
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah it works cool. Its pretty basic one i missed it . Tought of it duh . anyways thank you for heads-up . cheers